# Sorting items into bins in MATLAB

Tags: sorting, matlab, histogram, binning

If I have a set of data Y and a set of bins centered at X, I can use the HIST command to find how many of each Y are in each bin.

```
N = hist(Y,X)
```

What I would like to know is if there is a built in function that can tell me which bin each Y goes into, so

```
[N,I] = histMod(Y,X)
```

would mean that Y(I == 1) would return all the Y in bin 1, etc.

I know how to write this function, so I am only wondering if there is already a built-in in MATLAB that does this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The related function `histc` does this, but it requires you to define the bin edges instead of bin centers.

```
Y = rand(1, 10);
edges = .1:.1:1;
[N, I] = histc(Y, edges);
```

Computing the edges given the bincenters is easy too. In a one liner:

```
N = hist(Y, X);
```

becomes

```
[Nc, Ic] = histc(Y, [-inf X(1:end-1) + diff(X)/2, inf]);
```

with Nc == N, plus one extra empty bin at the end (since I assume no value in Y matches inf).
See `doc histc`.

Comment: Actually, the conversion between bin centers and bin edges is non-trivial if the bin centers are not evenly spaced.  MATLABs hist command actually gets this wrong, I think.  But yeah, this is good enough.  Thanks.

Comment: Currently, Matlab documentation recommends using `discretize` to obtain `Ic` in this example.

Answer (score 2):

If one is satisfied with using bin edges instead of bins,

```
[N,bin] = histc(y,binedges)
```

works.  Aaargh, MATLAB your function definitions are so nonintuitive